# Renaming an item in a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onresume

I have a ListView that contains the list of notes I have created.

I have overridden the method `onItemLongClick()`, which shows two options: **Delete** and **Rename**.

For the **Rename** option I want that a dialog be shown with a EditText and two buttons: Save or Cancel, so that user can change the name of any note he desires.

I know this can be done using dialogs but don't exactly know how to implement it.

Please explain how I can achieve this.

Comment: Try the [Android Developers Dialogs Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show a dialog with two buttons and edit text.And you have to do something like this

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Activity.this);
            alert.setTitle("Rename");

            final EditText input = new EditText(Activity.this);
            alert.setView(input);


            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String srt1 = input.getEditableText().toString();
                //update your listview here 

                }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

on the click of rename button add the custom dialog which shows edittext and two buttons save and cancel..and on the click of save button rename the value in the listview